# How to develop a AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) for XPath?

Tags: xpath, syntax, tree, abstract, abstract-syntax-tree

Could anyone teach me how to develop an AST(Abstract Syntax Tree) for XPath?
Totally confused.
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Parse XPath and make an AST of XPath ?  Or use XPath to walk an AST (which XML pretty much is directly)?

Comment: I want to parse XPath and make an AST of XPath.

Comment: How is that different than parsing Pascal and wanting to get an AST for Pascal?  Nobody is going to teach you anything, if you can't demonstrate that you have the basic concepts and have made an attempt to do something.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have just read some chapter of dragon book of Compliers, and understood the AST. Now I'm trying to use ANTLR to build the AST for XPath. Do you think this is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ANTLR is a fine way to get started doing this.

BUT: build something simple, like an expression parser, **first**.  This will make sure you understand the basics.  You'll likely find dozens of examples of this for ANTLR, I suspect even here on stack overflow.

After you get an expression grammar and an AST for it, *then* consider XPath.  You'll discover this is a LOT more complicated, mostly because the definition of XPath was created by one committee, building on the giant XML construction of another committee.  So your problem will be a little bit knowing how to build ASTs with parsers, and a LOT with reading all the gook that those two committees wrote to define XPath.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am following your suggestions now.