# AST for XPATH Queries

Tags: python, xpath, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any python module which can be used to normalize the XPATH queries and then generate an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)?

`//users/user[login/text()=\'admin\']` is one of the example.

Comment: Don't know exactly for Python, but the question of creating an AST for XPath has been discussed before:  e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167449/ddg#20170051

Answer (score 0):

## [eulxml.xpath](https://eulxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xpath.html) – Parse and Serialize XPath

> Functions and classes for parsing XPath expressions into abstract syntax trees and serializing them back to strings.
>
> This module exports two key functions, parse() and serialize().
>
> `eulxml.xpath.parse(xpath_str)`
>   Parse a string XPath expression into an abstract syntax tree. The AST will be built from the classes defined in eulxml.xpath.ast.
>
> `eulxml.xpath.serialize(xpath_ast)`
>   Serialize an XPath AST expressed in terms of eulxml.xpath.ast objects into a valid XPath string.